# AWS Rolling Deploys

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, amazon-ecs

I am trying to decide whether I should go for AWS-ECS or AWS-EB for a web app. The web app consists of 1 **nginx** container, 1 **php-fpm** container, a container for **cron** jobs and another for **supervisord**.

If I run a task consisting of nginx, php-fpm, cron and supervisord in a service, a rolling deploy would be straight forward as I could just update the service's task definition assuming I have the available resources.

However, here's my problem:

If I decide to horizontally scale later on, I must only have 1 cron container and 1 supervisor container run alongside multiples of nginx and php-fpm containers.

### How would it be possible to perform rolling deployments while ensuring that all containers, including the single cron and supervisord containers upgrade in lockstep?

Again, I cannot have more than 1 cron or supervisord containers at all. Even if I had 5 nginx and php-fpm containers.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want, or can't, have these all in independent services? Doesn't sound like something that needs to be tied together.